# Node - For Loop to update database not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use for-loop to update Blank fields in the database 
Using query if to get the blank fields(able to get  the data )  if the result length is greater than 0 (if condition ) then run the for loop and update the fields

In console.log able to print the expected result

```js
server.get('/updatelogout', (req, res) => {

  // Get checkout pending users data
  const query = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('OutTime', '=', 'null');
  datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
    const tasks = results[0];
    const newData = JSON.stringify(tasks);
    const parsed = JSON.parse(newData);
    const Vdata = parsed;
    const VdataCount = parsed.length;
    const Name = Vdata[0].Name;
    const Phone = Vdata[0].Phone;
    const UserId = Vdata[0].VID;
    console.log(VdataCount, UserId, Vdata);
    //Update logout time if any user logout is oending 
    if (VdataCount > 0) {
      const UserId = Vdata[0].VID;
      var event = new Date;
      console.log(UserId, event);

      for (var i = 0; j = Vdata.length, i > j; i++) {

        console.log(vuserId);
        const user = [{
          name: 'Date',
          value: Date,
        },
          {
            name: 'Name',
            value: Name,
          },
          {
            name: 'Phone',
            value: Phone,
          },
          {
            name: 'OutTime',
            value: new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-IN', {
              timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
            }),
          },
          {
            name: 'VID',
            value: UserId,
          },

        ];
        console.log(data);
        datastore.upsert({
          key: datastore.key(['VData', UserId]),
          data: user,

        });

      }
    } else {
      console.log('Do something');
    }

  });
});

server.get('/updatelogout', (req, res) => {

  // Get checkout pending users data
  const query = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('OutTime', '=', 'null');
  datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
    const tasks = results[0];
    const newData = JSON.stringify(tasks);
    const parsed = JSON.parse(newData);
    const Vdata = parsed;
    const VdataCount = parsed.length;
    const Name = Vdata[0].Name;
    const Phone = Vdata[0].Phone;
    const UserId = Vdata[0].VID;
    console.log(VdataCount, UserId, Vdata);
    //Update logout time if any user logout is oending 
    if (VdataCount > 0) {
      const UserId = Vdata[0].VID;
      var event = new Date;
      console.log(UserId, event);

      for (var i = 0; j = Vdata.length, i > j; i++) {

        console.log(vuserId);
        const user = [{
          name: 'Date',
          value: Date,
        },
          {
            name: 'Name',
            value: Name,
          },
          {
            name: 'Phone',
            value: Phone,
          },
          {
            name: 'OutTime',
            value: new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-IN', {
              timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
            }),
          },
          {
            name: 'VID',
            value: UserId,
          },

        ];
        console.log(data);
        datastore.upsert({
          key: datastore.key(['VData', UserId]),
          data: user,

        });

      }
    } else {
      console.log('Do something');
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error, or the db is not getting updated

Comment: Not getting any error aslo bd is not getting update

Comment: Do you get logs from the `console.log` inside the for loop?

Comment: No - for loop is not running

Comment: Try to `console.log(Vdata.length)`just before the foor loop. If it is `0` your for loop will not run.

Comment: The result is greater  than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this code, you can get what is the error at least.

```
server.get('/updatelogout', async (req, res) => {
// Get checkout pending users data
const query = datastore.createQuery('VData').filter('OutTime', '=', 'null');
const results = await datastore.runQuery(query);
console.log(results);
const tasks = results[0];
const newData = JSON.stringify(tasks);
const parsed = JSON.parse(newData);
const Vdata = parsed;
const VdataCount = parsed.length;
const Name = Vdata[0].Name;
const Phone = Vdata[0].Phone;
const UserId = Vdata[0].VID;
console.log(VdataCount, UserId, Vdata)
//Update logout time if any user logout is oending 
if (VdataCount > 0) {
    const UserId = Vdata[0].VID;
    var event = new Date;
    console.log(UserId, event)

    for (var i = 0, j = Vdata.length; i > j; i++) {

        console.log(vuserId)
        const user = [{
                name: 'Date',
                value: Date,
            },
            {
                name: 'Name',
                value: Name,
            },
            {
                name: 'Phone',
                value: Phone,
            },
            {
                name: 'OutTime',
                value: new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-IN', {
                    timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
                }),
            },
            {
                name: 'VID',
                value: UserId,
            },

        ];
        console.log(data)
        const response = await datastore.upsert({
            key: datastore.key(['VData', UserId]),
            data: user

        });
        console.log(response)

    }
} else {
    console.log("Do something")
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Nayan but still db is not getting updated and no error

Comment: what is the log printing in line console.log(response)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in the for loop is problematic I think:

```
for (var i = 0; j=Vdata.length,i>j; i++)
```

1. Your declarations of variables should come before the first `;`, so `var i = 0, j = Vdata.length`
2. What's between the two `;` is an expression that should evaluate to `true` in order for the for loop to be ran. Here you have `i > j`, so if i is `0` as you just declared it, and `Vdata.length` is greater than `0`, the loop will not run. I think you want `i < j`.

But generally, I think you have few things wrong in your code.

You probably want to choose one user per loop run, so you should put your line `const UserId = Vdata[0].VID;` inside the loop replacing `0` with `i` so that it iterate with the loop going on.

Also in your user object defined inside the loop, you pass `Date` as a value. You probably ment `event` that you try to define earlier, but without the parentheses neede: `var event = new Date();`.